# Recordar usuario y contraseña asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc

Tengo un formulario de inicio de sesión, con los campos de nombre de usuario y contraseña y aparte un checkbox de "recordarme". Quiero que cuando se marque el check y el usuario salga de su sesión, cuando vuelva a entrar al navegador se queden guardados el usuario y contraseña en los textbox.

Tengo este formulario en mi vista:

```
<form action = "@Url.Action("Login", "Home")" method = "post">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Usuario" id="username">
  <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Contraseña" id="password">

  <input id="ckb1" type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="Y" />
  <label for="ckb1">Recordarme</label>

  <button type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">Ingresar</button>
</form>
```

Y en el controlador:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login()
{
   string mat = Request.Params["username"];
   string pin = Request.Params["pass"];
   string recuerdame = Request.Params["remember-me"];
   bool persitente = recuerdame == "Y";

   FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(mat, persitente);

   return RedirectToAction("", "Home");
}
```

¿Cómo puedo guardar los valores del username y la contraseña para colocarlos en los textbox cada que abra el navegador?

Intenté colocando esta condición pero después no sé como mostrarlos en los textbox

```
if (persitente)
{
   Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
   Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(30);
 }
 else
 {
   Response.Cookies["UserName"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
   Response.Cookies["Password"].Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
  }
   Response.Cookies["UserName"].Value = mat;
   Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = pin;
```

Comment: Probaste implementando cookies?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera intenté guardarlos de esta manera `Response.Cookies["Password"].Value = pin;` por ejemplo para la contraseña, pero no sé cómo mostrarlos de nuevo en los textbox

Comment: Es una muy, muy mala practica guardar el password en una cookie, localstorage o sessionstorage, ningun lugar de almacenamiento en el lado cliente es buena idea, por más que lo cifres, es muy facil robar esa información. Si vas a almacenar algo en el lado cliente deberia ser un Token (JWT, OAuth, etc) o manejalo con session en el lado servidor.